# What's the right way to make a $http call that can be resolved in ui-router with TypeScript?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular-ui-router, typescript1.4

I've got a simple HTTP service that I hit via a service;

```
module shared {

    export interface IAuthService {
        isAuthenticated: () => any;
    }

    export class AuthService implements IAuthService {
        static $inject = ['$http'];

        constructor(private $http:ng.IHttpService) {
        }

        isAuthenticated():any {
            return this.$http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'http://localhost/auth'
            });
        }
    }

    export var app:ng.IModule = app || angular.module('shared', ['ngResource']);
    app.service('AuthService', AuthService);
}
```

And I use it in a route resolve;

```
$stateProvider.state('app', {
            url: "/app",
            abstract: true,
            templateUrl: "app/menu.html",
            controller: 'AppController',
            resolve: {
                authService: 'AuthService',
                isAuthenticated: function (authService) {
                    return authService.isAuthenticated();
                }
            }
        });
```

The problem is, I use HTTP response codes for the result -- if the user is authenticated, I send back some JSON data (hence the any return type until I build the class). If not, I return HTTP/403.

This worked ok in JS, perhaps by coincidence, but it seems in migrating to typescript, the 403 now stops the resolve dead in its tracks and the app just sits there.. Has anyone come across this? Is there a more correct approach?

EDIT: I was asked for the JS that's generated -- the .state is identical, the service gets converted into this;

```
AuthService.prototype.isAuthenticated = function () {
                return this.$http({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: this.ConfigService.apiBaseUri + '/authentication/authenticated',
                    headers: { 'Authorization': this.ConfigService.sessionId }
                });
            };
```

Comment: It might be very useful to show the javascript as well. As it is actually the javascript which is being executed.  Even compare the original javascript and the new javascript.

Comment: On a side note, I played around with authentication with angularjs for while and ended up using a http interceptor which was checking for 401 in all requests and redirecting when needed. If you want I can share some code. It works good if the authenticated pages require data.

Comment: Added the generated JS. I would appreciate the code, it might be handy elsewhere, but I still need to understand why resolve doesn't work as expected -- i.e. 404 does the same thing, and that's a perfectly legit response code in normal operation that doesn't require a redirect..

Comment: https://gist.github.com/dylanmckendry/61107901bfa2b0f8d16e

I am using constants for all the injectors... also I could not get a factory working using a class (well in a nice way).

Answer (score 2):

So the answer turns out to be pretty obvious in retrospect.. A rejected promise rejects the state transition as well. So the correct solution when there might be a failure of a $http call that should proceed anyway, is to add a .then(function(data) {//...},function() {//...}) to the call inside the resolve method. In my case;

```
isAuthenticated: function (authService) {
    return authService.isAuthenticated().then(function(data) { return data; }, function() { return null; });
}
```